# What is the C# extension methods equivalent for my Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

How to use extension methods to form the second query as the first one.
By the way this must to get all last element of groups.

```
 1) var res = from element in LI
      where element.C_ID != null
      group element by element.C_ID
            into groups
            select groups.OrderBy(p => p.C_ID).Last();
```

(second query is not well formed)
my be because groups not ordered

```
 2) LI.Where(element => element.C_ID != null)
     .GroupBy(element => element.C_ID)
     .Last().ToList()
```

Comment: Your query is missing a select ;)

Comment: The C# specification describes exactly how query comprehension expressions are converted into method calls; consult it for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LI.Where(element => element.C_ID != null)
 .GroupBy(element => element.C_ID) //a sequence of groups
 .Select(group => group.OrderBy(p => p.C_ID).Last()) //select the last of each group
 .ToList()
```

Comment: Yep. Was being literal... might not matter if it's being converted to sql. If Linq2Objects, definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As to the comment to [spender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357/spender) answer:

```
LI.Where(element => element.C_ID != null)
 .GroupBy(element => element.C_ID) //a sequence of groups
 .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(p => p.C_ID).First()) //order in descending order and then get first of each group
 .ToList()
```

Comment: you are missing a `First`

Comment: This would give you `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SomeType>>`, not  `IEnumerable<SomeType>`

Comment: Thank you guys (@Selman22, @spender) for your valuable comments!

Answer (score -1):

You can make the `OrderBy` before the `groupby` method, like that:

```
LI.Where(element => element.C_ID != null)
     .OrderBy(element => element.C_ID)
     .GroupBy(element => element.C_ID)
     .Last().ToList()
```